# Mysql insert doesn't work when the input field has an apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql

For first time I have a mysql problem.
I have an input field such as

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" id="myfield" />
```

So when the user presses the submit button I am getting the value with php

```
$myval = $_POST['myfield'];
```

Everything is ok so far. 
If my value in this input field contains an apostrophe `'` and for example:

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" id="myfield" value="Niko's Dog" />
```

the mysql query:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (myfield) VALUES ('$myval')");
```

Fails to insert the data..

Any opinions please? I need all characters to be valid.

Comment: Make use of `Prepared Statements` and you can stop worrying about this escaping and stuff. ! You are currently using `mysql_*` functions which is deprecated.

Comment: `mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (myfield) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($myval)."'");`

Comment: just a suggestion, instead of `mysql_query` use `mysqli_query` as its more secure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to **add slashes** like

```
$myval = addslashes($myval);
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (myfield) VALUES ('".$myval."')");
```

Either you can use **mysql_real_escape_string** directly.

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (myfield)
              VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($myval)."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you don't escape your input

```
INSERT INTO users (myfield) 
VALUES ('Niko's Dog')
             ^-----------string end
```

You better use *prepared statements*. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), to avoid escape issues, as well as malicious input:

```
$result;
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (myfield) VALUES (?)") {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $myval);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo "Your result is $result";
    $stmt->close();
}
```

You ahould also be using  `mysqli_*`, as the old `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never ever trust user input! Always filter it before using, because user is evil (you have to think like that while writing any software).

Also, you should skip using deprecated `mysql_*` and instead use eg. `PDO` (or `mysqli_*` if you want to use something more similar to `mysql_*`) which is very easy and gives you more possibilities. Eg. allows you to use `prepared statements`. Using this allows you to write safer and better software.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code into your server side file. so it will check every field of your form.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_array($value)){
        $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

other than `addslashes` and `mysql_real_escape_string` you can also use `str_replace` for the same:

```
$myval=str_replace("\'","'","$myval");
```